# TikZ does not draw any function

Tags: tkz-fct

The following code used to work but does not work anymore.
What is the issue?

Thanks

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\tkzInit[xmin=-1.25,xmax=3,ymax=2]

\tkzFct[ultra thick, color=blue!50!black, samples=1000]{sqrt(\x+1)}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The console gives this message

> Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.7.dylib
> Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/glib/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib
> Reason: image not found system returned with code 6

PS: I tried to `brew reinstall libffi` but it does not make any difference.

Comment: Looks like this has little to do with LaTeX, rather with your UNIX system. (consider doing a full upgrade of your system and reboot the machine?)

Comment: If I understand the `tkz-fct` manual correctly, `\tkzFct` uses `gnuplot` which means TeX needs to be called with `-shell-escape`, gnuplot must be installed and correctly at that. Maybe try to (re)install?